# How to properly point domain to IP? And why does IP not work when entering in browser?

Tags: dns

When I use a [tool](https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html) to find out the ip address of my website I get this: **94.130.19.155** This is also what my backend tells me. Unfortunately when I enter this in my address bar I end up at a completely different website.

Why is that? Have I configured something wrong?

Secondly when I try to set up [Custom DNS Record](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w661ju9gdb4fih5/Screenshot-2017-09-17-20.58.jpg?dl=0)s with the accordant IP I get linked to this random site which is not what I want. When I use the tick for automatically generated DNS Records, the entries look exactly the same (@ A 94.130.19.155) and the site works (although I get some redirect chains I want to avoid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web service provider is using something called *Name Based Virtual Hosting*, which means you do **not** have a dedicated ip address for your site. Instead there are **multiple websites running on the same ip address**, and the server must know which site to display based on the hostname which is sent by the browser in a separate header.

If you use the ip address directly in the browser, the web server has no idea which site on that ip address you are trying to access and will probably serve the first site listed in its configuration file.

Likewise, if you register your own domain name and try to point it to the shared ip address, the web server will not recognize your domain name and does not know which site to display. Your own domain name will have to be configured in the web server, and this requires some support from the hosting provider (i.e. might cost you extra).

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not understand that there can be multiple websites running on the same ip address. If I understand this right there is no way I can set up this myself?

In my backend there is this Option which is enabled by default: "Manage the DNS records for this domain using the control panel"

Also there is the additional information: "If you uncheck this option, you will need an own DNS server and you will have to update your DNS server manually."

I suppose I have to keep that option checked unless having my own server? (the reason for all this: redirect chain)